# Too long response from my app deployed on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm very new in using Heroku.
I deployed my telegram-bot using free plan on Heroku to test how it works. But it works great only first 2-3 minutes, after that period of all responses from the app take up to 6 hours per each!

In documentation: app will sleep after 30 minutes of no-requests, but I can't find any info about requests take 5-6 hours for response by using free plan.

I tried autodeployment and manual deployment, same situation.
Source code is on GitHub.
Deployment on local machine works great 24/7.

Thank you in advance!

UPD:

It tryes to bind to some $PORT after 90 secs of starting app. Have no idea what does it mean.
After crushing heroku restarts app, sometimes restarts are succeed, sometimes are not.

Logs:

Mar 09 20:43:37 javamethodabot app/api Build succeeded

Mar 09 20:44:49 javamethodabot heroku/web.1 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Mar 09 20:44:49 javamethodabot heroku/web.1 Stopping process with SIGKILL

Mar 09 20:44:49 javamethodabot heroku/web.1 Process exited with status 137

Mar 09 20:44:50 javamethodabot heroku/web.1 State changed from starting to crashed

Mar 09 20:44:50 javamethodabot heroku/web.1 State changed from crashed to starting

Comment: This isn't normal, but without more information we can't help. Do you have any logs? Can you provide a [mre]? Please read [ask].

Comment: I add logs in my question above. Thanx!

Comment: "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch"—well, are you binding to the port given by the `PORT` environment variable? Is this a web application that should receive HTTP requests? If it is a web application and you aren't binding to `PORT` your app should _never_ work.